# How can you invoke headless chrome using C# process on a mac?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to invoke headless chrome to take a screenshot. Currently using a snippet like this:

```
'''
    Process proc = new Process {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                FileName = @"/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome",
                Arguments = "--headless --screenshot --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw " 
    + htmlFileName,
                UseShellExecute = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
'''
```

but I receive the error: The file /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome does not exist

When I run it on linux it works when I change the FileName field to "google-chrome"

What string do I need to pass it on a mac?

Comment: as it is called `FileName` - i guess it is a file name (suprisingly)

Comment: hmm... as you intend to invoke headless chrome, I guess it is chrome executable?

Comment: Ok, seriously. I don't have a macbook by hands, but 1st thing I would try is to not escape every space char in `FileName`.